# Universal Links (iOS) - Como abrir la aplicación mediante URL evitando el pop up?

Tags: ionic, ios, capacitor

como estan?

Me encontre con un problema al abrir mi aplicacion hibrida (Ionic/Capacitor) mediante Universal Links, en el cual esta todo configurado pero a la hora de usar el link tenemos el Pop Up que dice "Open App in ...?.

Existe alguna manera de evitar que aparezca este PopUp?

Muchas gracias!
Que tengan un buen dia

Comment: ¿Y dónde está tu código? Sugiero que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

ese pop-up es una ventana de sistema y no es posible evitarla.

Por temas de privacidad iOS pregunta al usuario si quiere abrir la nueva aplicación.